# cudaMemcpyToSymbol use details

Tags: eclipse, cuda, memcpy, nsight, tesla

I am trying to move data structures from host to constant memory on a Tesla C1060 (compute 1.3). With the following function:

```
//mem.cu
#include "kernel.cuh"

int InitDCMem(SimuationStruct *sim)
{
  SimParamGPU h_simparam;

  h_simparam.na = sim->det.na;
  h_simparam.nz = sim->det.nz;
  h_simparam.nr = sim->det.nr;

  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_simparam, &h_simparam, sizeof(SimParamGPU));
}
```

The data structure (in a header file):

```
//kernel.cuh

typedef struct __align__(16)
{
  int na;
  int nz;
  int nr;
} SimParamGPU;

__constant__ SimParamGPU d_simparam;
```

The problem is that it seems the values are not being copied to the constant memory in the GPU.

Do I need to re-declare `__constant__` on `\\mem.cu` like stated in [cudaMemcpyToSymbol do not copy data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261984/cudamemcpytosymbol-do-not-copy-data).
Should I use `extern` somewhere?

There are no errors, the values are always set to 0.

Comment: Are you sure you can compile your code? `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()` syntax you used doesn't seem right. Have a look [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gf268fa2004636b6926fdcd3189152a14.html#gf268fa2004636b6926fdcd3189152a14).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've shown.  I built a test [here](http://pastebin.com/Bkfbh4Us) ; no issues.  SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  Voting to close -- lack of an SSCCE.org code.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621380/cuda-how-to-access-constant-memory-in-device-kernel-when-the-constant-memory-is) may be of interest, but based on your description, everything needed is in the same compilation unit.

Comment: Well, since I have compute capability 1.3 the compilation unit has to be one for `__constant__`. I was asking for a way around that limitation and... more importantly... if that could be the reason I am seeing values equal to 0 on the registers while those values are set properly on the host side.

Comment: [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586545/cuda-5-0-namespaces-for-constant-memory-variable-usage/19590487#19590487) on a possible solution. In Nsight how can I configure the Generate Relocatable Device Code option? Apparently I cannot since my compute capability is 1.3

Comment: @mrei Nsight Eclipse Edition enables Generate Relocatable Device Code when you check "Separate compilation" on the Build/Settings project property page.

Comment: @Eugene, I found your answer in another post and tried it. But when I select "Separate compilation", compute capability 1.3 to Generate PTX/GPU codes are not available (only 2 and up).

Comment: @mrei no separate compilation for 1.3 devices…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your kernel? `d_simparam` is in the same "translation unit" as your host code from compiler point of view - you don't need any "extern" declarations here. You may need one in the source file where your kernel is.

This is what works for me:

*device.h* - file with device symbols:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct SimpleStruct {
    int a;
    float b;
};

__constant__ SimpleStruct variable = { 10, 0.3f };

__global__ void kernel() {
    printf("%d %f\n", variable.a, variable.b);
}
```

*host.cu* - host code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(value) {                                      \
    cudaError_t _m_cudaStat = value;                                    \
    if (_m_cudaStat != cudaSuccess) {                                   \
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %s at line %d in file %s\n",             \
                cudaGetErrorString(_m_cudaStat), __LINE__, __FILE__);   \
    exit(1);                                                            \
} }

#include "device.h"

int main(void) {
    const SimpleStruct n = { 7, 0.5f };

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(variable, &n, sizeof(SimpleStruct)));

    kernel<<<1, 1>>>();

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaThreadSynchronize()); // Wait for the GPU launched work to complete
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaGetLastError());
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceReset());

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:** Separate compilation is only supported on SM 2.0 devices and newer. It is not possible to use separate compilation for SM 1.3 code.

Comment: and if my `__constant__` is in a header file included in the host.cu file?

Comment: Where's the kernel code? #include is a textual operation - preprocessor would simply put whole header into the source file. You'll need to have kernel code included below your constant variable declaration.

Comment: @mrei In my example, rename device.cu into device.cuh and replace both "externs" in host.cu with a single #include "device.cuh" - I just tried it, it works.

Comment: the kernel call is in another complitely different source file

Comment: You will have to put kernel code into the same source file (either directly or using #include)

Comment: it should work for me too... but the values in registers (d_simparam) are all set to 0, different from what I have in h_simparam. Gonna try with `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice`, like in your example, at the end of `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`.

Comment: I am using `#include kernel.cuh` where I do the kernel call.

Comment: Have you tried my example with replacing externs with #include, as I suggested in a comment above?